# Android 4.4 - Send SMS Generic Failure - Service Bluetooth Link

Tags: c#, android

I wonder if someone can point me in the right direction. I am programming an Android 4.4 App. I have a Service running listening for connections on the Thread that is started from the same Service. If I run the following it works:

```
async Task SendSMSAsync(string TextMessage)
{
await Task.Run(() =>
{
PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this.context, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this.context, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage(Chris, null, "This is a Test", sentIntent, deliveredIntent);
});
}
```

However, If I pass a String into the SendTextMessage Method. I get a Generic Failure.

```
activity.bluetoothSocket.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
string TextMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
...
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage(Chris, null, TextMessage sentIntent, deliveredIntent);
```

My string is only 10 chars long.

```
buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(activity.DataReceivedString);
activity.writeData();
```

I get back the correct String.

'Chris' is a string and this is my number hard coded and does not change.

This is very odd.

Answer (score 1):

Well, very odd, the answer is the Buffer:

```
private byte[] buffer = new byte[157]; // 160 was supposed to be the limit...
```

I dropped the size down:

```
private byte[] buffer = new byte[70];
```

Now it works.

Poor documentation is a source of confusion: [Android.Telephony.SmsManager.SendTextMessage Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Telephony.SmsManager.SendTextMessage/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/Android.App.PendingIntent/Android.App.PendingIntent/)